# Autodesk forge Document Bowser click on any thumbnail show error in console

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Autodesk forge loaded .rvt file able to view document browser and thumbnails.
When click on thumbnails showing console error and loading symbol.

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
Promise.then (async)        
_tryLoad    @   Panel.js:229
n.onTreeNodeClick   @   TreeViewDelegate.js:49
(anonymous) @   Tree.js:572
```

Comment: provide more context

Comment: @norbekoff

.rvt file uploaded via autodesk api. then translate file also done with 100%. when it render in bowser it show the the file. but when click on document browser icon it show all the thumbnail but click on that thumbnail it showing console error in browser

Comment: (1) Can you reproduce it with any Revit file? (2) You face the same issue if you select an item on the "Tree" tab instead of the "Thumbnails" tab? (3) Which version of the Viewer are you using? (4) Did you translate the model to SVF or SVF2?

Comment: problem solved we are using pdfjs and autodesk also using pdf. so pdf.worker has conflict that has been solved